# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite (fatal error: 80: problem wrapping app data)

Tags: ssl, jetty, httpclient, handshake

I am using the jetty (9.4.12.v20180830) HTTPClient in-order to invoke the REST API.

The SSL/TLS handshake is failing with the below exception trace.

We are IBM java 1.8 version.

jdk.tls.client.protocols is defined as TLSv1.2
    SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled
    SUPPORTED: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
    SERVER_DEFAULT: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
    CLIENT_DEFAULT: [TLSv1.2]
    IBMJSSE2 will enable CBC protection
    Using SSLEngineImpl.
    IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default
    IBMJSSE2 will not require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken
    IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert check during renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default
    IBMJSSE2 will allow client initiated renegotiation per jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation set to FALSE or default
    IBMJSSE2 will not allow unsafe server certificate change during renegotiation per jdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange set to FALSE or default

```
Is initial handshake: true
%% No cached client session
HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, fatal error: 80: problem wrapping app data
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, called closeOutbound()
HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, closeOutboundInternal()
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 50                               ......P

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:110)
        at

jdk.tls.client.protocols is defined as TLSv1.2
    SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled
    SUPPORTED: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
    SERVER_DEFAULT: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
    CLIENT_DEFAULT: [TLSv1.2]
    IBMJSSE2 will enable CBC protection
    Using SSLEngineImpl.
    IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default
    IBMJSSE2 will not require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken
    IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert check during renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default
    IBMJSSE2 will allow client initiated renegotiation per jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation set to FALSE or default
    IBMJSSE2 will not allow unsafe server certificate change during renegotiation per jdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange set to FALSE or default

    Is initial handshake: true
    %% No cached client session
    HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, fatal error: 80: problem wrapping app data
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
    HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
    HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, called closeOutbound()
    HttpClient@21ffc2b4-32, closeOutboundInternal()
    [Raw write]: length = 7
    0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 50                               ......P

    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:110)
            at
```

Below is the sample code used,

```
public void initialise() {
        /*
         * This is to suppress Jetty logging framework, otherwise it will log
         * errors & traces into stderr. Create and set a dummy Jetty Framework
         * as the Jetty logger class.
         */
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class",
                "com.ibm.tivoli.netcool.integrations.transportmodule.JettyLoggerSink");

        if (sslEnabled) {
            try {
                logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Initializing secure connection");
                if (keyStoreFilename == null || keyStorePassword == null) {
                    throw new Exception(
                            "Key store filename or password not set.");
                }
                SslContextFactory sslContext = new SslContextFactory(false);
                sslContext.setKeyStorePath(keyStoreFilename);
                sslContext.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);               
                sslContext.setProtocol("TLSv1.2");                
                sslContext.start();
                client = new HttpClient(sslContext);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                initialise_successful = false;
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * Non-SSL client initialization
             */
            client = new HttpClient();
        }
        try {
            client.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            initialise_successful = false;
        }
        initialise_successful = true;
        logger.log(Level.FINEST,
                "HTTP client has been successfully initialized");
    }
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is wholly a result of the non-standard JVM that IBM maintains (it does not conform to the Java JVM standard, nor the SSL/TLS standard).

The heart of your specific issue is that IBM JVM does **not** use the RFC standard names for the SSl/TLS cipher suites for some reason.

You'll have to configure, manually, the cipher suites excludes and includes to have any hope of functionality.

To start with, use `SslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites()` once to set the excludes to blank and try again. (this clears out the cipher suites known to be vulnerable).

The default list of excluded Cipher Suites is a combination of what the JVM excludes, the OS libraries excludes, and [what Jetty excludes](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.29.v20200521/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L126-L138).

```java
// Jetty Exclusion List

private static final String[] DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_CIPHER_SUITES = {
    // Exclude weak / insecure ciphers
    "^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$",
    // Exclude ciphers that don't support forward secrecy
    "^TLS_RSA_.*$",
    // The following exclusions are present to cleanup known bad cipher
    // suites that may be accidentally included via include patterns.
    // The default enabled cipher list in Java will not include these
    // (but they are available in the supported list).
    "^SSL_.*$",
    "^.*_NULL_.*$",
    "^.*_anon_.*$"
};
```

Then, before you decide to use this vulnerable configuration, you'll have to manually declare the IBM JVM named cipher suites you want to limit your use to via the `SslContextFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(...)` call.

Comment: HI @joakim, thanks for quick answer. why should we care about including and excluding the ciphers?. the underlying JVM should take care of this right based on the protocol/keystore/truststore that we used. Because in my case I don't know what ciphers are supported at server(api provider) side.

Comment: Jetty 9 supports Java 8 through Java 15 atm.  Relying on the underlying JVM is against common security policies.  Even within a single specific version of Java, such as Oracle Java 8, the range of behaviors with Cipher Suite options is vast across it's multi-year lifespan.  And then there's the fact that folks just don't pay attention to JVM expirations (which is super critical to pay attention to if you use SSL/TLS). Finally, the rest of the world moves faster then the JVMs when it comes to SSL/TLS configs.

Comment: Thanks, As you said it seems a problem with the JRE that I was using, when I change the JRE its starts working fine :)